# circle :after not perfectly round

Tags: sass

The circle I'm making is not totally round, the sides seems to be cropped, when it's bigger than 18px or 10px it looks perfect. the problem seems to be between 10px and 18px. why is that?

Pug:

```
section.article-main-sidebar
  .article-main-sidebar-breadcrumb
    ul(class='breadcrumb-list  circular-shape_color-category_'+one_badge)
      li(class='breadcrumb-list-item1')
        a(class= 'breadcrumb-list-item1-shape1')
          span(class= 'text text1') text
```

SASS:

```
&:hover{
            &::after{
              content: '';
              width:12px;
              height: 12px;
              left:9px;
              top:4px;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 20;
              border-radius: 50%;
              transform-origin: center;
              animation: grow 0.2s ease-in-out;
            } 
          }
```

Comment: What selector are you applying the `:hover` state to?

Comment: the :hover is apply to to the a